# Porting C++ code to VBScript, overflow with bitwise operators

Tags: c++, vbscript

I am trying to port the following C++ code to VBScript, but I am having a problem due to overflow when trying to use the bitwise XOR operator.

`buffer` is an integer array (size = 6).

```
ris.ID_OPER = atoi(buffer);

  for( i=0; i<=5; i++ )
    chk += (unsigned long)(buffer[i]);
  chk = chk ^ ris.ID_OPER;
  chk = chk & 0xff;
  sprintf( buf, "%02X", chk );
```

VBSCRIPT - CODE

chkbin = Clng(chkbin)

chkbin = 1 Xor 11110001001000000

Overflow error is raised (Overflow: '[number: 1,1110001001E+16]')

Comment: Suggestions for what? You haven't told us what issues you're having. Might want to _edit_ your post and include that tidbit there.

Comment: Can you please include your current VBScript code and the exact error message that you are receiving?  Please see http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to create a question that is more likely to attract high quality answers,

Comment: as requested i've included the VBSCRIPT code that is generating the error

Comment: i've found the problem , Xor works on int double directly .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

An overflow as I think any good developer should know is your data storage variable is not big enough to hold the value after it has shifted. One or more bits have "dropped off" the start or end depending on whether big or little Endian binary is "behind the scenes". Try CDbl() or a currency type instead of Clng(). VB Script has one bit less for the C++ unsigned value because it is using a signed long (one bit is holding + or -) , there may be another way other than using a bigger data type, have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/12/03/integer-arithmetic-in-vbscript-part-two.aspx

Maximum values for signed and unsigned

Unsigned long.

4294967295

Long.

2147483647

Just 1 less bit means the highest value available is roughly half

At very last resort use CCur() because a currency also holds larger numbers values and is capable of storing more than a long.